# Highcharts tool tip marker color change

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts, frontend

I have a multi-line graph in **highcharts.js** that i,m working with and i want to change the color of tool tip marker that appears when you hover over a line.

Any idea how can i achieve this ? Which property should i add and in which section ?

[image]

The reference code is as below :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the `pointFormat` attribute in the tooltip object.

```
tooltip: {
  valueSuffix: '°C',
  pointFormat:'<span style="color:red">\u25cf</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/eoonsp1g/
documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat

Comment: @simon was it helpful ?